# Escape '.' in JMESPath

Tags: jmespath

I have a JSON object in which I wish to retrieve the value of a property that contains a dot in its name using JMESPath:

```
{
  "a": {
    "b.c": "value"
  }
}
```

In this example I wish to retrieve *value*. How can I achieve this?

Comment: I have the same question.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I just figured it out.  I'm working in python, but I think the solution is the same for any implementation.  Basically, any key name with special characters need to be quoted within the search string.  With your example:

```
import jmespath

test_dictionary = {
  "a": {
    "b.c": "value"
  }
}

jmespath.compile('a."b.c"').search(test_dictionary)
```

Result: `'value'`