# Ansible how to filter dict key with double colon ::

Tags: ansible, jmespath, json-query

Trying to filter "10.17.101.149" with a json_query.
From this data:

```yaml
{
  "fact": { 
    "network::ipv4_address": "10.17.101.149",
    "network": "test"
  }
}
```

My json_query:

```yaml
- name: "get ip address"
  hosts: test
  connection: local
  vars:
    vm: {
  "facts": { 
    "network::ipv4_address": "10.17.101.149",
    "network": "test"
  }
} 

  tasks:

    - debug:
        msg: "{{ vm.facts | community.general.json_query(jms) }}"
      vars:
        jms: "network\"::\"ipv4_address"
```

I do not find the right way to escape the double colon "::" in "network::ipv4_address". I tried different ways to escape but no correct ones.
`jms: "network\":\"\":\"ipv4_address"`
`jms: "network\":\":\"ipv4_address"`
`jms: "nework\"*\"ipv4_address"`

I've checked the docs. Ansible yaml does not give much info about a colon. https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/YAMLSyntax.html

Comment: Is there a reason for you to use `json_query` to start with? `- debug: var=vm.facts['network::ipv4_address']` will do the job too.

Comment: Thank you @β.εηοιτ.βε  I think i really miss a good understanding of the tool. When i see a pure dictionary {   }, i always think a json_query is the tool to use. I wish there was a guide that helps orientating people with this kind of stuff.

Comment: The thing is, YAML is just a superset of JSON. And Ansible data structures are loaded in Python thanks to YAML processing. So, yes, as long as you know that, it becomes clear that JSON and YAML alike are to be addressed like any other variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Escaping characters in Jmspath/json, should be be done by enclosing the whole "key" by quotes.

This one works. `jms: '"network::ipv4_address"'`

This post gave me the answer. [Escape '.' in JMESPath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56872738/escape-in-jmespath)

For some reason the official doc, did not help. Looking again at the official doc, i find this https://jmespath.org/proposals/raw-string-literals.html but its unfindable when your are not searching for raw string literals. Basically chicken and egg issue when you do not know "programming" theory and the right terminology. Luckily SO is here.